# PHP - Read file from remote server

Tags: php, remote-connection

So I have two CentOS servers.

On server1 I have a log in the directory `/home/something/logs/latest.log`

On server2 I have my apache server, and I want it to read the log on server1.

I need to do this because I want to make a real time console, displaying data from the log on server1

I will get the data from the log in one PHP file and then do some ajax in another file and then I have a real time log.

My questions:

How can I read a file from a remote server with php?

Does anybody know a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick visit to the PHP docs will tell you that it's incredibly easy to do :-)

But in summary, all you need to do is:

```
$myfile = file_get_contents("http://server1/blah/blah/file.log");
```

Note: though... for this to work, you will need that file to be accessible, via a web server running on server1, since it's a static file, then installing something like NginX and just placing the doc in the default root (or pointing the default root at the home folder) will be enough to allow you to use the PHP get file contents call.

If, putting a web server on server1 is NOT an option, then essentially your going to have to follow these steps.

- Connect to server1 using something like SSH/Telnet, or one of the remote copy utils, or set up an FTP server and point it to your home folder.
- Use one of PHP's many connection methods (Which one, depends on the service you chhose above)
- Then create a script that, connects using the selected connection method in step 2, automates any parameters needed, and connects.
- Once connected, issue any commands needed (Depending on the connection method used) to grab the file and it's contents.
- Disconnect from the server and process the file.

With SSH, you'll need to use the SSH2 functions built into PHP (Again, the doc's are on php.net), there's a class documented there you can use.

For Telnet, similar difference, but A) I wouldn't recommend it and B) you'd need to do a lot of code to support the telnet protocol over raw sockets.

For FTP, well PHP has (and has for a long time) had FTP support baked in, but as with a web server, you'll need to install and set up FTP, then secure it and all that jazz, if your going to do this, then it's easier to get it working with a web server.

Beyond that, well you could adopt the *nix philosophy of many small tools, and use exec and system calls to run programs from your Linux distro, such as 'rcopy', 'sftp' and many others, but again that's quite a task, to know what to automate, where and how.

You also have the option of writing your own ad-hoc server, that listens on a socket, and sends the log when a connection is made.

Lastly, you could feasibly also share a folder using NFS or Samba, then just use normal file open/read/close calls as though the file was local, but then you've got to set up users, shares, auth and a load of other things.

Which route you go, depends on how much work your willing to do, and what restrictions you do/don't have preventing you from using any of the methods outlined here.

My advice though, go the web server method, use NginX, minimal config, seal the log file server away behind closed doors and let php do what it's good at, and grab the file over http.

Comment: Thank you for the wise words. I think I will go with the solution, with installing a webserver on server1 (Maybe on of the others).                                                                                               People here on superuser are for some reason more freindly than people from stackoverflow